# Death Penalty for Insurance Company Directors

Tags: the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy

In Hitchhiker's [Mostly Harmless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostly_Harmless), at the end of Chapter 14, Trillian and Arthut have this convo:

> Trillian: The insurance business is completely screwy now. You know they've reintroduced the death penalty for insurance company directors?
>
> Arthur: Really? No I didn't. For what offense?
>
> Trillian: What do you mean, offence?
>
> Arthur: I see.

I don't understand the meaning of this conversation. Is Trillian implying that insurance company directors just get the death penalty, simply from being assigned the position?

Comment: Yes, she's saying that Insurance Company Directors are automatically assigned the Death Penalty in view of their clear deficiencies, in much the same way that I think we can agree that anyone standing for high office should automatically be disqualified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you've understood the main thrust of the humour here. What Trillian is saying is that the new law assumes that being an Insurance Company Director is *prima facie* evidence of their unworthiness as a person, and hence punishable by death. Obviously in the long term this isn't a sustainable stance (who'd volunteer to become a director if it meant being executed?) but that's part of the joke.

It's perhaps a little easier to grasp where Adams is coming from once you understand that in British society, insurance companies have garnered something of a poor reputation over the years due to their tendency to refuse to pay out on [valid claims](http://www.mirror.co.uk/money/525000-peoples-claims-rejected--7249128) or intentionally dragging their feet on claims in the hopes that the claims-holders will get bored, give up or conveniently die. The people who run these companies are therefore considered to be about as trustworthy as politicians or estate agents (and about as useful to society as telephone sanitisers, hairdressers or management consultants).